# Ошибка PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, iis

есть сайт запущенный на IIS, разработанный на фреймворке Yi2. Все прекрасно работало, но на днях комп на котором стоял сайт, поменяли на новый и следовательно нужно было этот сайт теперь поставить на новом компьютере. Поставил IIS, PHP, перекинул исходники сайта, ничего абсолютно не менялось, установил `php_pdo_mysql`  , но столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

```
Database Exception - yii/db/Exception
could not find driver 
Caused by: PDOException
```

Скрин ошибки:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgfz1.png

Скрин PHPInfo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcnPY.png

Comment: Пробовали: php-mysql установить?

Comment: Да, с экстеншенами все окей, я даже попробовал выдернуть папку php из компа, где сайт работает, но не помогло